# The GDI text display problem （I just use GDI and not use Unity or DirectX）

Tags: c++, user-interface, gdi

I am writing a program game and want to show a text on the game's beginning.

I have checked the syntax of the program to guarantee there is no problem.

But the text can't display on the window.

I declare two global variables HDC：

```
   HDC g_hdc, g_mdc;
```

The first is used to display, the second is used to buffer.

The text display code:

```
   HFONT hFont = CreateFont(45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GB2312_CHARSET, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
   SelectObject(g_hdc, hFont);
   SetBkMode(g_hdc, TRANSPARENT);
   wchar_t text1[] = L"Begin！";
   SetTextColor(g_hdc, RGB(50, 255, 50));
   TextOut(g_hdc, 0, 0, text1, wcslen(text1));
```

This code is included in the function `init()` so the code will be used when the windows create and just use only once.

When I run this program I just got this :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ekc7.png)

You can see the bitmap show correct but the text is not.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I never use those apis directly but I think that code shouldn't run only once but every time the window need to be repainted (in response to `WM_PAINT`). Also, avoid global variables and take advantage of c++ libraries and constructs.

Comment: This API is called GDI. And you need to repaint window content (all or some) in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT`.

Answer (score 1):

I find why it can't display. I change the way of get HDC form `PaintBegin()` to `GetDC()` then the text begin to display. The `PaintBegin()` looks like only using when `WM_PAINT` message be caught.

Comment: You might take a look at the source code to [WinBGIm](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi).  It is an implementation of the Borland BGI API (with some helpful extensions such as mouse input) implemented entirely in GDI and serves as an example of using GDI in code without an event handling message loop. Full details at https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/bgi.html.